# Why can't Kotlin infer the type for this HashMap with a nullable value type?

Tags: java, kotlin, hashmap

When I run this code, I get a `Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.collections.HashMap<String, Int> /* = java.util.HashMap<String, Int> */ but kotlin.collections.HashMap<String, Any?> /* = java.util.HashMap<String, Any?> */ was expected` error

```
data class Record(
        var blah: HashMap<String, Any?>
)
    
fun test2() {
        val data2 = hashMapOf("key" to 10000)
        val a = Record(data2)
        println(a.blah)
}
```

Run the above on Kotlin Playgrounds: https://pl.kotl.in/vL2n_Qrwo

I only get this error when the type in the data class is a HashMap, I don't get it when it's just a Map (https://pl.kotl.in/f1V3Eeyj-). Why is this? It's fixed by explicitly specifying Any? (Any with a question mark, to specify that it's nullable) in the hashMapOf type so `hashMapOf<String, Any?>("key" to 10000)`

The weirdest thing is if I don't create a new variable `data2` to hold the hashmap, it doesn't return any error!

```
data class Record(
        var blah: HashMap<String, Any?>
)
    
fun test1() {
    val a = Record(hashMapOf("key" to 10000))
    println(a.blah)
}
```

Run this one on Kotlin Playgrounds: https://pl.kotl.in/K12q1Bd7B

As you can see, no errors. It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 6):

The inference engine only analyses one statement at a time.

The question is about the inference of the two type arguments to [`fun <K, V> hashMapOf(): HashMap<K, V>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-map-of.html), i.e. the types of `K` and `V`.

In the first example, `val data2 = hashMapOf("key" to 10000)`, there is no requirement given for the result of `hashMapOf()`, so the engine uses the parameter to determine the two types. `"key" to 10000` is a pair of `String` to `Int`, so the result is that `K` is `String` and `V` is `Int`.

In the second example, `val a = Record(hashMapOf("key" to 10000))`, the `Record` constructor *requires* that the type of the object returned by `hashMapOf()` *must be* an object that is assignment compatible with `HashMap<String, Any?>`. The inference engine therefore uses `K` as `String` and `V` as `Any`, and compilation accepts that, since `"key"` is compatible with `String` and `10000` is compatible with `Any?`.

Comment: Can you address why the inference in the OP's first example is different when `blah` is a `Map<String, Any?>`?

Comment: ah that makes perfect sense Andreas for my second (and most perplexing) question, thanks. Isn't that a bit of a downside of the kotlin plugin? Shouldn't it be smart enough to figure it out? Anyway, I second what @HenryTwist says, any ideas with the first question? I know this is against SO protocol and I should have split up questions. I suspect the answer is related to Kotlin mapOf returning any Map type while hashMapOf specifically returns a Java HashMap

Comment: A downside compared to what?  Java isn't any smarter about this kind of inference.

Comment: @LouisWasserman well this isn't an issue at all on Java as I would have to explicity specify the HashMap K, V types of `data2`. It's just something I thought Kotlin could figure out

Comment: It doesn’t read ahead to the next line when determining a type. Nor should it, in my opinion. Any line of code should be determinant in its meaning without any subsequent code affecting that meaning.

Comment: @Andreas but why does it work with a `Map` though?

Comment: @YassinHajaj I've answered that in a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the first part of your question, a `HashMap` (or Kotlin `MutableMap`) is defined with generic parameters `K` and `V`, whilst a read-only `Map` is defined with generic parameters `K` and `out V`.

The `V` for a `Map` can have the `out` modifier because a `Map` is read-only, and therefore the value is only present in the "out" parts of its function signatures -- in other words, values of type `V` are only returned from the `Map`, never provided to the `Map`. See [Declaration-site Variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance).

As noted in the answer by @Andreas, the inferred type of `hashMapOf("key" to 10000)` is `HashMap<String, Int>`.

When you define:

```kotlin
var blah: HashMap<String, Any?>
```

the compiler says: no, I can't take a `HashMap<String, Int>` and assign that to a variable of type `HashMap<String, Any?>` because someone could validly put something other than an `Int` in here later, which would clearly be incorrect.

You can tell the compiler "no, its ok if something other than an Int goes in here" by changing your assignment expression to explicitly specify the type, and then all is well:

```
val data2 = hashMapOf<String, Any?>("key" to 10000)
```

Correspondingly, when you define `blah` as a read-only `Map` rather than a mutable `HashMap` (or Kotlin `MutableMap`):

```kotlin
var blah: Map<String, Any?>
```

the compiler is OK with assigning a `HashMap<String, Int>` to it, because now `Any?` has `out` variance i.e. `blah` can only return `Any?`'s, not accept them.

Comment: ah that explains it, thanks @Raman! HashMap is mutable (because it's Java) while Kotlin Map is not. I just tested changing blah to `MutableMap<String, Any?>` and that returns the error

Comment: @georgiecasey You got it. I added `MutableMap` to the answer.